# Как работать с API, находящимся на GitHub в Android приложении?

Tags: android, kotlin, api, retrofit2, gson

Мне нужно получить курс валют с помощью этого API (в  Android приложении):
https://github.com/exchangeratesapi/exchangeratesapi

В писании проекта говориться о том, что использовать в GET, однако я никак не могу понять, где взять URL, по которому я буду получать данные с помощью Retrofit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это проект апи, то есть прежде чем начать с ним работать вам нужно будет его у себя где-то развернуть. Например на локальном сервере, [вот здесь](https://github.com/exchangeratesapi/exchangeratesapi#deployment) есть раздел как его разворачивать. Ну и после удачного разворачивания у вас будет доступно апи для работы. Если вам принципиально нужно данное апи и то как оно работает, то я бы советовал изучить принцип его работы, как происходит разворачивание и настройка. Если же вам нужно просто бесплатное апи для получения курса валют, то можно например воспользоваться популярным сборщиком апи [RapidAPI](https://rapidapi.com/collection/currency-converter-exchange-api) и выбрать что-то по своим требованиям. Вот есть ещё одно [бесплатное апи](https://apilayer.com/marketplace/currency_data-api#), с максимально доступным кол-вом запросов 250 запросов/месяц

Comment: получается я должен скачать репозиторий, запустить его в PyCharm, а затем ввести команды pipenv shell и pipenv install?

Comment: не обязательно, можно и командную строку использовать это без разницы, вы просто спросили где вам взять урл, я и ответил что для начала нужно будет запустить и поковыряться в коде))) либо вариант попроще - посмотреть в сторону бесплатных апи)

Comment: Вот оно же тут 250 запросов/месяц развернуто: https://exchangeratesapi.io/

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, ну так-то да, просто может человеку нужно прям чтобы свое было)) курсы валют все-равно нужно будет извне собирать :D

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, спасибо!